# JavaScript Geolocation for Blackberry 8530

Tags: blackberry, geolocation

I've been unable to acquire the location of any Blackberry 8330 or 8530 using JavaScript. Is this a known bug? I'm using regular blackberry.location methods, and it works for other models.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try with http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/, not sure which version of BlackberryOS you are using but this is the best option you have, you can check the supported platforms on: http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/wiki/SupportedPlatforms